# How to create an IValueConverter to do conversions between strings and list in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

The Converter should be able to convert a `List<SomeObject>` to a `string`. Perhaps it is joining them or anything else - that's not the problem im facing.

The main problem is that the *bindingsource* might be a `ObservableCollection<T>` or a `List<T>` or some other `IEnumerable<T>` implementations. Somehow a list of the original type must be retrieved there in the `ConvertBack()` Method.

Comment: Better is subjective. "What do you need?" is (or should be) the question. If it works, it works. Which begs the question: Does it? If it does, the question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, if it doesn't, we need to know *what* doesn't work. As it is, I'm voting to close it as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt this is a question i posted with the option "answer it yourself" - If someone has that problem too here's one solution. No need to be closed.

Comment: Which I'm sure could be turned into an excellent post, presented on your own personal blog. As it is, it's not a question suited for Stack Overflow. It's a Q&A site, not a How-To site, nor a personal blog.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt the whole "I have a problem and I know the solution" behavior is actually encouraged on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Default: It seems it is. I don't concur, because in that case, I'm sure I (and anyone else) can come up with a few 100 solutions to problems. But as it stands, I will (reluctantly) retract my close vote, as it does seem to be in the spirit of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt I understand you. The point is i've not found anyone with the same problem on SO or even blogs with this theme (allthough i didn't dig too deep). So all I wanted to do, is to document my solution to this specific problem.

Comment: No worries, it's a democracy here, give & take, can't have it all ;) I would suggest to elaborate on your answer though. Perhaps requirements, assumptions, replace "SampleClass" with something more appropriate. Document the code, with tips, as it were (for instance: You need to split the string on _something_, why not make it a property of the converter so end users can specify which string to split on).

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt thats a cool tip. thank you.

Comment: Hell, I'll even upvote it, if you elaborate ;)

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Ur so cute ;*

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved the problem. A Targetlist is beeing recreated at runtime.

```
public class AnyListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const char delimiter = ';'; // delimiter to join
    private const char[] delimiters = new[]{';', ',', '.', ':', ' '}; // possible delimiters, which might be in the string when converting back

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var list = value as IEnumerable<PhoneNumber>;
        if (list == null)
            return null;

        // Do conversion here
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var sample in list)
        {
            sb.Append(nummer.ToString()).Append("; "); // join it to a string
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var valuestring = value as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valuestring))
            return null;

        // Do some conversion back to some List
        //var list = (from sampleString in valuestring.Split(....) select new Sample(sampleString)).ToList();

        // For example conversion back
        var list = numbersstring.Split(delimiters).Select(phoneNumber => phoneNumber.Trim()) // split the string
            .Where(phoneNumber => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber)) // sort out hollow Nuts :)
            .Select(phoneNumber => new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber)) // recreate Phonnumber Objects
            .Where(numberobj => numberobj.IsValidPhoneNumber) // Test if the result is a correct Phonenumber
            .ToList();

        // Convert to the Targetlist by invoking its constructor, passing the created list.
        var converted = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType, list);
        return converted;
    }
}
```